# Conditional formatting base on other column's date that match today in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I have a attendance table. I need to highlight column A who did not fill in record.
Column A is name. 
 How can I use "conditional format" to highlight "Jackson" who did not fill attendance record today when today is 03/08/2022?

My current "conditional format" on Column A is

```
=C2<>""
```

It is work but I need to change conditional format day by day.

| column A | Column B | Column C | Column D | Column E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| -------- | 02/08/2022 | 03/08/2022 | 04/08/2022 | 05/08/2022 |
| John | 10:00 | 10:00 | -------------- | -------------- |
| May | 10:00 | 10:00 | -------------- | -------------- |
| Jackson | 10:00 | -------- | -------------- | -------------- |

I don't want to add another reference column between Column A and Column B to index where match today.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below formula to CF rule

```
=INDEX($B$3:$E,MATCH($A3,$A$3:$A,0),MATCH(TODAY(),$B$2:$E$2,0))=""
```

[image]

Comment: Great! It work fine and you save me a lot!

Comment: @PaulChung If it helps then please tick mark the answer (accept it as solved).